# Fiware cepheus cep subscription to context broker issue

Tags: subscription, fiware, complex-event-processing, broker

I wanted to make the cepheus cep receive incoming events from the context broker rather than the cepheus broker but then I checked the cepheus-cep logs when I uploaded the config.json file and found that it doesn't subscribe to the entities in the context broker as there's no subscription launched. Also when I tried send the subscription manually on behalf of the cepheus-cep and started to send messages to the entities in the context broker, the Cepheus-cep treated the notifications as mere post request not as eventin messages that should be processed and it displays a message stating "POST method not supported".

So, what could be the solution for both issues regarding the Cep subscription to context broker and the manual subscription I made?

Comment: Update your question with more details: config information, code, errors you are facing, etc.

Comment: Can you copy/paste some detail configuration of the CEP or broker configuration.